# In the IDLE shell 3.10.2 I am trying to write a series of if statements and it will not let me

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to Python but am following along a book closely. I can't figure out why this won't work. When I click return to write a new line below the second "if" statement, the code attempts to run and says invalid syntax, highlighting the second "if"

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTVep.png)

Comment: it looks like there is a space in your print statement

Comment: Its not refrencing the if, the if is highighted as it can not be run as the line before it is the one causing the syntax issue. And like Talha siad, there is a space between your print and brackets so its affecting the if statement

Comment: @TalhaTayyab I removed the space & didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interactive window of IDLE knows that a block will follow an `if` statement, and expects that block to be ended by an empty line. According to the image of your code, you only used a backspace, and then IDLE expects an unindented part of the `if` instruction, said differently an `else` or `elsif`.

TL/DR: use an empty line to end an indented bloc.

---

The interactive window is... interactive! It executes one statement at a time. If you want to prepare a full script and then execute it as a whole, you must create a new file (menu File/New) write the full script and save it to disk at execution time (<kbd>F5</kbd> of menu Run/Run Module).

Comment: How do I use an empty line? If I click "return" to make an empty line, and then click return again to start typing a new line, the code attempts to execute

Comment: @Julia: If you are in the interactive window you must execute one statement at a time...

Comment: so it is impossible in the interactive window to write two if statements back to back?

Comment: @Julia: Yes because they are distinct instructions and they are executed one at time. But please see my edit...